# SAP FIORI: Hide Sharing and Author Columns in Manage Variants Pop-up - Variant Management

Tags: sapui5, variants

Can someone guide me in hiding **Sharing** and **Author** Columns in **Manage Variants** pop-up of VariantManagement Control in SAP Fiori.

[image]

**Follow up 1** :

**XML Code**:

```
<v:VariantManagement variantItems="{variantsModel>/Variants}" standardItemText="{variantsModel>/DefaultVariant}" select="onSelectVariant" save="onSaveAsVariant" enabled="true" manage="onManageVariant" showExecuteOnSelection="false" id="variantManagement" showShare="false">
<v:variantItems>
    <v:VariantItem text="{variantsModel>VariantName}"
        key="{variantsModel>VariantKey}" />
</v:variantItems>
```

[hide Author Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW6S4.png)

Comment: Please see [ask]. The idea is that you tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and tell us what results you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property

> "showShare" = "false"

Here is a sample code:

```html
<vm:VariantManagement standardItemText="text" showShare="false"></vm:VariantManagement>
```

Comment: Hi @Nandan, even if try to use the above property, "showShare" = "false", in the manage variant pop-up, the Author Column persists. I've update the xml code and Screenshot for reference.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @pandu , code I have written above will only remove the sharing column. I couldn't see a reference to remove author column .